# Download Async + Copy = Copiando imagem 0 bytes

Tags: c#, multithreading, async

Estou fazendo download simultaneo de várias fotos, e também preciso fazer a cópia para uma determinada pasta.

O que acontece é que ele faz a cópia antes de terminar o download.

```
public static async Task DownloadData(IEnumerable<FotosProdutos> urls, int id)
        {
            var urlTasks = urls.Select((url, index) =>
            {
                //corrigo possíveis erros na url
                var urlTratada = url.Url.Replace(" ", "").Replace("\n", "");

                using (var wc = new WebClient())
                {
//Caminhos.FolderImg é uma const do tipo @"C:\files\"
                    var path = Caminhos.FolderImg +  url.FileName;


                    var downloadTask = wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(urlTratada), path);
//aqui é minha tentativa de só fazer o copy depois q estiver ok, porém com esse if nunca é executado.
                    if(downloadTask.IsCompleted)
                    {
                        File.Copy(Caminhos.FolderImg + url.FileName, Caminhos.FolderImg + @"\tb\" + url.FileName);
                    }



                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - DownloadFtos {1} - {2}", DateTime.Now, index.ToString(), id.ToString()));

                    return downloadTask;
                }
            });

            await Task.WhenAll(urlTasks);
        }
```

**Exemplo resumido da fotosProdutos**

```
public class FotosProdutos()
{
 public string Url {get; set;}
 public string FileName {get; set;}
}
```

Como entender que determinada task finalizou (fez download ) e assim posso fazer o copy?

pensei em fazer fora do WhenAll algo do tipo

```
 await Task.WhenAll(urlTasks);

            foreach (var item in urlTasks)
            {
                if (item.IsCompleted)
                {

                }
            }
```

Mas como saberia qual das urls ele já processou? estou com dificuldades.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qualquer código que colocar a seguir a `await Task.WhenAll(urlTasks);`sé será executado quando todas as *task* terminaram.

Poderá aí então fazer a cópia de todos os arquivos descarregados:

```
    .....
    .....
    await Task.WhenAll(urlTasks);

    foreach (var url in urls)
    {
        File.Copy(Caminhos.FolderImg + url.FileName, Caminhos.FolderImg + @"\tb\" + url.FileName);
    }
}
```